# How can I add a namespace tag to XML using System.XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to add a namespace tag to an XML document using system.XML in C#
Here is my code so far:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

XmlElement invHeaderTag = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "InvoiceHeader", string.Empty);
doc.AppendChild(invHeaderTag);
```

The image below show the XML I am trying to create.

[image]

How do I create the namespace tag?

Comment: Did you try `doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:ns0", "othernamespace_Invoices");`?

Comment: thanks for your input, can you please expalin where to put that, I tried this: doc.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:ns0", "_Invoices"); without success

Comment: Try to use XDocument and XElement it is much easier to use and will save a lot of youre time.

Comment: I understand, so there is no answer to my question. you are refering to something else, and Alexei refer to a post that has no accepted answer